# Get "TypeError: Key must be a buffer" when DELETE an Object using "ibm-cos-sdk"

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I want to implement a REST API to control the access to an IBM Bluemix Object Storage. The POST method is implemented and works fine, but there is a problem by deleting the created object, because I get de following error:

```
TypeError: Key must be a buffer
```

The code looks like this:

```
var AWS = require('ibm-cos-sdk');
var util = require('util');
var config = {
  endpoint: <endpoint url>,
  apiKeyId: <api key code>,
  ibmAuthEndpoint: 'https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token',
  serviceInstanceId: <instance code>,
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
};

var cos = new AWS.S3(config);

app.delete('/<path>/:id',function(req, res){
  cos.deleteObject({
    Bucket: <bucket>,
    Key: req.params.id + '.pdf'
  }, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
      res.send({"message":"error: " + err});
    } else {
      console.log("data: " + data);
      res.send({"message": "success"});
    }
  });
});
```

Does someone know the problem and can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue is when one of the encryption libraries encounters a string or buffer that's similar to a string or buffer but isn't actually one. I'm a little curious how that happened, though it shouldn't matter for this issue.

It turns out it's caused by `signatureVersion: v4` which has the SDK building signatures it doesn't need. Removing `signatureVersion` from your config should fix it. That will default back to the `iam` signature type, which is what is used with API keys.